# what is the other method for this code?

Tags: php

i have a following code.
i have a array of month.

```
         $m="";
         $months = array(1=>'January',2=>'February',3=>'March',4=>'April',5=>'May',6=>'June',7=>'July',8=>'August',9=>'September',10=>'October',11=>'November',12=>'December');

         foreach($objhst_fees->fetch_hst_fees("`month`,`fees`","where `grno`='".$stu_name['grno']."'")as $count_month)
          { 
                           //value like:$count_month['month']=1,2,3
            $m  .= $count_month['month'].",";
          }
```

so assume $m=1,2,3,4,5,
then,i explode it and create array.

```
          $paid_month = explode(",",$m);
          $arr=array();
          foreach($paid_month as $key=>$p)
          {
            array_push($arr,$p);
          }
```

and then, i print the month name which is not in `$arr`.

```
          foreach($months as $key=>$a)
          {
             if(!in_array($key,$arr))
             {
                echo $a.",";
                //echo $months[$key];
             }
           }
```

but i think,this method is to long for it.so what is the alternatives for doing this?

Comment: So your expected result for `1,2,3` would be `January,February,March`, right?

Comment: yes,but if `$arr` contain `1,2,3` then output is `april,may,june...dec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code:

```
foreach($objhst_fees->fetch_hst_fees("`month`,`fees`","where `grno`='".$stu_name['grno']."'")as $count_month) { 
   //value like:$count_month['month']=1,2,3
   $m  .= $count_month['month'].",";
}
```

you could change:

```
$m  .= $count_month['month'].",";
```

to

```
$m[] = $count_month['month'];
```

which will avoid need to explode() it again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$m = array();
$months = array('', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

foreach( $objhst_fees->fetch_hst_fees("`month`,`fees`","where `grno`='".$stu_name['grno']."'")as $count_month)
{
    $m[] = $count_month['month'];
}

foreach ($months as $key => $month) {
    if (in_array($key, $m)) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $month . ',';
}
```

You don't need to concatenate the $m as string and then explode it.
Also notice a small change in my `$months` array. I removed the keys. But to preserve them starting with `1` value I simply added an empty value at first (zero) position.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$paid_month = explode(",", $m);
$paid_months = array();
foreach($paid_month as $p) 
{
    $paid_months[$p] = (isset($months[$p]) ? $months[$p] : 'Unknown');
}
print_r($paid_months);
```